# List views do not scroll smoothly

Tags: android

I have two list views. I need to scroll one list view automatically
when the other list view is scrolled. both list views should have this ability

i implemented the onScrollListner in both listviews

for listview 1

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
if (l1.getChildAt(0) != null) {
    Rect r = new Rect();
    l1.getChildVisibleRect(l1.getChildAt(0), r, null);
    l2.setSelectionFromTop(l1.getFirstVisiblePosition(), r.top);
    }

}
```

for listview 2

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
if (l2.getChildAt(0) != null) {
    Rect r = new Rect();
    l2.getChildVisibleRect(l2.getChildAt(0), r, null);
    l1.setSelectionFromTop(l2.getFirstVisiblePosition(), r.top);
    }

}
```

I have 2 problems regarding this

1 - the lists do not scroll smoothly. (not like normall listview)

2 - I can only scroll both listviews using one list view.(when i scroll using l2
 both get scrolled. but it does not work when i scroll using l1. both stay fixed)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It happened becoz you put listview inside listview :)

You can achieve you problem using this.

suppose L1 is inside L2 then

```
L1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {

                if(arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
                {
                L2.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's your application so you could do whatever you want but I am confused with what you want to achieve. The sole idea of having two list views is to have separate representation of two different categories of data so that they can be accessed(scrolled or selected) separately.
If you have requirement of representing two categories of data that need to be displayed side by side as a list then you can have a list row with two columns. 
something like this will work:
[image]

You can populate these two rows with different kind of data and this can be scrolled together.

Comment: your answer made me to think differently. i fixed my problem using grid view . thanks

Comment: A grid view is a better option. With grid view handling clicks on different column items will be easier. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found out a different way to get the same result. I remove my two list views and replaced it
with a grid view with two columns. this way i can scroll both without implementing onScrollListner and i can even use the custom adapter i used for the two listviews.